# Grep is not grepping

Tags: terminal, grep

And I always thought that + is 1 or more and * is 0 or more...

```
echo sample text | grep --color s*e\b
echo sample text | grep --color s+e\b
```

both versions is not grabbing the word sample

Comment: try `grep --color -P 's.*?e'`

Comment: try `grep --color -E 's*e\n'`

Comment: @PS Working but do I have to use Perl ? :/

Comment: @PUG thats not perl, `-p` means `PCRE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of asterisk or plus sign is a multiplier.

Moreover you need to better enclose grep pattern in single quotes.

In your case this would work:

```
grep --color 's.*e\b'
```

Asterisk is multiplying the dot after s = any character, so with above command you are asking grep to bring you texts starting with `s` plus any other characters (`.`) for mutliple times (`*`) plus an `e` and all this to be separated by a word bountary `\b`.

Your initial command `grep --color 's*e\b'` will match words that have letter s multi times (*). For example you will catch the `ssssse` word bellow:

```
echo "ssssse text" | grep --color 's*e\b'
```

There are other ways also to do this job.

Comment: Great but I don't understand why this is working :
echo sample text | grep --color 's.*e\b'
And this is not :

echo sample text | grep --color s.*e\b

Comment: @PUG Manual page of grep describe that patterns to be matched must be enclosed in single quotes.... without quoting the pattern , the results could be wrong (as has been proved in your tests).